# Reattribution of values based on a reversed rank

Tags: r, rank

I have been stuck on a very simple task, reattributing values of a column to another column based on a reversed rank.

Here is my trial with a reproducible example :

```
df <- data.frame(sum_values = c(1, 20, 11, 30, 5))
df$rk <- rank(df$sum_values) # Calculate ranks based on sum_values
df$rkr <- length(df$rk) + 1 - df$rk # Calculate reversed ranks 
df$sum_reversed <- df$sum_values[order(df$rkr)] # attribute reversed sum_values based on reversed rank
```

When I print the result, I think the attribuation has been made based on the initial order of the observation rather than the reversed rank, and I really don't know how to solve this issue.

Comment: can you be clear what your expected output is?

Comment: Do you want something like `df$sum_reversed <- df$sum_values[match(df$rkr, df$rk)]` ?

Comment: The same but using `order` `df$sum_values[order(df$rk)][df$rkr]`

Comment: @GKi thanks it works perfectly. I am sorry for the late answer. If you give a real answer I will validate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `match` to get the *reversed rank*.

```
df$sum_reversed <- df$sum_values[match(df$rkr, df$rk)]
#df
#  sum_values rk rkr sum_reversed
#1          1  1   5           30
#2         20  4   2            5
#3         11  3   3           11
#4         30  5   1            1
#5          5  2   4           20
```

or using `order`.

```
df$sum_values[order(df$rk)][df$rkr]
#[1] 30  5 11  1 20
```

Maybe use `order` instead of `rank` for the case there are two equal values:

```
rank(c(1,1,2))
#[1] 1.5 1.5 3.0

rank(c(1,1,2), ties.method = "first")
#[1] 1 2 3

order(c(1,1,2))
#[1] 1 2 3
```

---

In case there are two equal values the reverse rank need to be estimated different.
Simple sorted data:

```
DF <- data.frame(x = c(1, 5, 5, 7, 9))
DF$rank <- rank(DF$x)
DF$rx <- rev(DF$x)
DF$rrank <- rank(DF$rx)
DF
#  x rank rx rrank
#1 1  1.0  9   5.0
#2 5  2.5  7   4.0
#3 5  2.5  5   2.5
#4 7  4.0  5   2.5
#5 9  5.0  1   1.0
```

In case it is unsorted.

```
DF <- data.frame(x = c(1, 7, 5, 9, 5))
DF$rank <- rank(DF$x)
i <- order(DF$x)
DF$rx[i] <- DF$x[rev(i)]
DF$rrank <- rank(DF$rx)
DF
#  x rank rx rrank
#1 1  1.0  9   5.0
#2 7  4.0  5   2.5
#3 5  2.5  7   4.0
#4 9  5.0  1   1.0
#5 5  2.5  5   2.5
```